# An example in symplectic geometry

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, convex-polytopes, group-actions, toric-varieties

$\DeclareMathOperator\SU{SU}$Let $M$ be a coadjoint orbit of dimension 6 of $\SU(3)$, and let $T$ be the maximal torus in $\SU(3)$. If we denote $\mu : M \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ the moment map associated to the action of $T$ on $M$, then the image of the moment map is a hexagon with vertices $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$, $F$ the images of the elements $M^T$ by $\mu $.

[image: hexagon with vertices labelled A, B, C, D, E, F]

For $P \subset \mathfrak{t}^*$ an affine space with vectorial direction $\overrightarrow{P}$, let $P^\perp \mathrel{:=} \lbrace \xi \in \mathfrak{t} \mathrel| \langle y, \xi \rangle =0, \forall y \in {(\overrightarrow{P})}^\perp\rbrace $, and let  $T_P$ be the sub-torus generated by $\operatorname{Exp}(P^\perp)$.

If
$\Sigma \mathrel{:=} \lbrace \text{$P$ convex polytope in $\mathfrak{t}^*$} \mathrel| \exists \text{$Z$ connected component of $M^{T_P}$ s.t $ \mu (Z)= P$}\rbrace$, how can I prove that $\Sigma = \lbrace\text{faces of $ \mu (M)$}\rbrace \cup\lbrace [AD],[BE], [FC]\rbrace$?

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376299/question-about-an-example-in-symplectic-geometry , and possibly also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/152589/how-to-find-faces-of-polytope-defined-by-a-weyl-orbit .

Comment: I think I don't understand the notation.  You use $P$ for an affine space, and then write $T_p$, which presumably should be $T_P$; but then you refer to $T_p$ (which maybe equals $T_P$) for $P$ a polytope, which is not an affine space.  Do you want to identify the polytope $P$ with its affine span?

Comment: Oh sorry for that ! But , yes you're right, I'll fix that .

Comment: I have been thinking about [my answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/376436), which originally purported to prove this but seems to prove [something else](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376429/an-example-in-symplectic-geometry/376436#comment954442_376436).  I can't see any way to get the diagonals of the hexagon in $\Sigma$.  Could you point to a reference that claims that they are there?

Comment: Actually, this was an example given in some notes written by one of my professors, when I asked him about how to find the set $\Sigma$ , he said that he used the set of generic stabilizers (which is finite),  namely the set $\lbrace T_m , m \in M \rbrace$, where $T_m$ is the stabilizer of m, and then to work with $\mu (M^{T_m})$!  But I'm still  confused how this works ! If you could that  would be great!

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by "[If you could](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376429/an-example-in-symplectic-geometry#comment955381_376429)".  Unless my argument (which does indeed, albeit indirectly, work with $\mu(M^{T_m})$) is wrong, this claim is false.

Comment: @LSpice I'm sorry , i just wanted to ask you,  if you have ideas how the hint given by my professor works ! But to be honest, my understanding of this was very little, since I'm a beginner in symplectic geometry

Comment: The approach you [mention](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376429/an-example-in-symplectic-geometry#comment955381_376429) is, as I [say](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376429/an-example-in-symplectic-geometry#comment955403_376429), more or less the one I used, but I wind up with a different conclusion.

Comment: @LSpice, I will confirm this claim, and edit my question if  needed ! Thank you so much for your help and your time I'de really appreciate it !

Answer (score 4):

$\DeclareMathOperator\Ad{Ad}\DeclareMathOperator\Cent{C}\DeclareMathOperator\Norm{N}\newcommand\fg{\mathfrak g}\newcommand\fl{\mathfrak l}\newcommand\ft{\mathfrak t}\newcommand\C{\mathbb C}\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$Based on your previous question [Question about an example in symplectic geometry](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376299/question-about-an-example-in-symplectic-geometry) and this one, it looks like you are working through some notes on symplectic geometry and moment maps.  It might be a good idea to gather your questions and see if you can unify them into one big one, rather than asking several different but closely related ones.

Put $G = \operatorname{SU}(3)$.  Let $\{\alpha, \beta\}$ be a system of simple roots of $T$ in $G$, and let $X^*$ be an element of $M$ that lies in the subset of $\fg^*$ that vanishes on all root spaces of $T$ in $\fg_\C$, which we identify with $\ft^*$.

For future reference, suppose that $g \in G$ is such that $\Ad^*(g)X^*$ is trivial on every root space in $\fg_\C$ other than the $\pm\alpha$-root spaces.  Let $L$ be the subgroup of $G$ whose complexified Lie algebra is the sum of the Lie algebra of $T$ and the $\pm\alpha$-root spaces in $G_\C$ (so $L$ is, as it were, $\operatorname S(\operatorname U(2) \times \operatorname U(1))$).  Then we may identify $\fl^*$ with the set of elements of $\fg^*$ trivial on every root space in $\fg_\C$ other than the $\pm\alpha$-root spaces.  Clearly, $\Ad^*(L\cdot\Norm_G(T))X^*$ is contained in $\fl^*$.  On the other hand, suppose that $g \in G$ is such that $\Ad^*(g)X^*$ lies in $\fl^*$.  Then $T = \Cent_L(X^*)$ and $g T g^{-1} =  \Cent_L(\Ad^*(g)X^*)$ are both maximal in $L$, hence are conjugate by an element of $L$; so $L g$ intersects $\Norm_G(T)$.

Let $T'$ be a subtorus of $T$.  We have that the fixed points of $T'$ in $\fg^*$ are those $Y^* \in \fg^*$ that vanish on every root subspace in $\fg_\C$ associated to a root that is non-trivial on $T'$.  In particular, this fixed-point space depends only on the collection of roots trivial on $T'$.  If this set of roots is non-empty (equivalently, if $T' \ne T$) and does not contain all roots (equivalently, $T'$ is non-trivial), then it is a singleton, hence a Weyl conjugate of $\{\alpha\}$.  Then we have shown that, up to Weyl conjugacy, $M^{T'}$ equals $\Ad^*(L\cdot\Norm_G(T))X^*$, whose components, indexed by $\Norm_L(T)\backslash\Norm_G(T)$, are $\Ad^*(L)X^*$, $\Ad^*(L s_\beta)X^*$, $\Ad^*(L s_\beta s_\alpha)X^*$.  The corresponding $P$s are, respectively, the edge between $\mu(X^*)$ and $\mu(s_\alpha X^*)$; the edge between $\mu(X^*)$ and $\mu(s_\beta X^*)$; and the diagonal between $\mu(X^*)$ and $\mu(s_\beta s_\alpha X^*)$.  In your labelling, these might be $[AB]$, $[AF]$, and $[AD]$.  Taking Weyl conjugates gives the other faces and diagonals.

Comment: Wait a minute, I now think that the components are actually the edges between $\mu(X^*)$ and $\mu(s_\alpha X^*)$ ($[AB]$), between $\mu(s_\beta X^*)$ and $\mu(s_\alpha s_\beta X^*$ ($[EF]$), and between $\mu(s_\beta s_\alpha X^*)$ and $\mu(s_\alpha s_\beta s_\alpha X^*)$ ($[CD]$), and I don’t see how to get the diagonals.  I will keep thinking.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and for your time @LSpice ! I'll be looking for the rest of it ! But to be honest, my understanding of this was very little, since I'm a beginner in symplectic geometry! Could you please recommend some good references about properties of convex hulls of coadjoint orbits and their relation with weyl group (As your answer seems to be based on)?

Comment: Most of this is just stuff I've picked up in the course of learning the general structure theory of reductive groups, rather than coadjoint orbits and symplectic geometry specifically.  Nonetheless, Kirillov is the master of the (coadjoint) orbit method; probably [Kirillov - Lectures on the orbit method](https://doi.org/10.1090/gsm/064) is a place to start.  There's a paper by Kottwitz called "Harmonic analysis on reductive $p$-adic groups and Lie algebras" ([MSN](https://mathscinet-ams-org.ezproxy.tcu.edu/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2192014)) that I seem to remember discusses these polytopes, too.

Comment: Oh Thanks @LSpice, these are  a worthwhile references

Comment: Hi @LSpice,  Could you please explain to me why the connected components of $M^{T'}$ = $\Ad^*(L\cdot\Norm_G(T))X^*$  are indexed by $\Norm_L(T)\backslash\Norm_G(T)$, $\Ad^*(L)X^*$, $\Ad^*(L s_\beta)X^*$ and $\Ad^*(L s_\beta s_\alpha)X^*$ ?

Comment: That's a good question.  It's clear that each $\operatorname{Ad}^*(Ln)X^*$ with $n \in \operatorname N_G(T)$ is connected, and that it depends only on $\operatorname N_L(T)n$; but I don't see at the moment why two such connected sets can't intersect.  I will think more about it. \\ In the meantime, did you clarify that the statement you were trying to prove was the correct one?

Comment: thank you for your answer! Regarding my question, i didn't have the opportunity  yet to ask  the professor who wrote the notes that I'm trying to understand, but from rereading them I think the set $\Sigma$ in my question is the same as the set $ \lbrace\bigcup\limits_{S_M \subset T'}  \mu(M^{T'}) , $ $T'\subset T$ and $T'/S_M$ is infinite $ \rbrace $. Where $S_M :=  \bigcap\limits_{m \in M} Stab(m)$  is the intersection of stabilizers in M, and there are five type of them. Please see this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3936484/diagonal-matrices-that-belong-to-conjugates-of-t

Comment: Then For each sub torus T' in T s.t $T' / S_M$ is not finite we take each connected component Z of $M^{T'}$, it's a  symplectic submanifold  of M provided with the restricted symplectic 2-form of M and the restricted moment map $\mu_{|Z}$. Applying the Atiyah-Guillemin-Sternberg convexity theorem to each connected component Z, we see that $ \mu(Z)$ is a convex polytope equal to $ Conv \lbrace \mu(F)$ , F is connected component of $Z^T \rbrace$

Comment: And realizing this, i start now to work with the  second description of the set rather then the first one in the  post ( wich i denote $\Sigma$ ) since it seems  much easier ! Please let me know if you've understand  what I've  written in my comments !

Comment: @Maria, I have not had a chance to think through your latest comments.  Is there a new question, or is it only more information / a different perspective?

Comment: it's a different perspective to find the set $\Sigma$ .

Comment: The last time he asked me to prove that  the set $ S_M $ contains 5 elements: $\lbrace T, T_e, T_1 ,T_2, T_3  \rbrace $ and then to prove that $\mu(T_1) = \lbrace \Delta_1, \Delta_2 , \Delta_3 \rbrace $ and  $\mu(T_2) = \lbrace \Delta'_1, \Delta'_2 , \Delta'_3 \rbrace $ and $\mu(T_3) = \lbrace \Delta''_1, \Delta''_2 , \Delta''_3 \rbrace $ where $\Delta_i , \Delta'_i \Delta''_i$ are the faces and the diagonals in the hexagon .

Comment: I apologize if my comments are very messy and too long, but please feel free to ask me to clarify any thing you don't understand in what I've wrought.